# How to publish Blazor WebAssembly with ASP.NET Core hosted

Tags: c#, blazor

I would like to know how do I publish a Blazor WebAssembly application with ASP.Net Core Hosted checked.
The big problem is that in the application they have 2 projects, and I don't know which one to publish, or how to merge between them when publishing.

Answer (score 6):

Publish the Server app.

When you look in its \bin\Release folder you will see the Client related DLLs as well.

Don't overthink it.

Answer (score 5):

You need to publish your Server project.

But it must have a reference to your Client's project.

In versions < 3.2.0 you must also register Blazor on your server application.

Here's how to register it in your server `Startup` (Replace Client with the proper namespace in your Blazor project):

```cs
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseBlazorDebugging();
            }
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseClientSideBlazorFiles<Client.Startup>();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToClientSideBlazor<Client.Startup>("index.html");
         });
     }
```

Comment: Note that this is changing, in the latest previews the `<Client.Startup>` references are gone. The Server project still references the Client but you could get rid of that if you wished. The server only needs to know _where_ the Client files are.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I`ve updated my answer to mention this as well!

Answer (score 1):

Publish the server project, it will include the client assemblies in its output,
Make sure you have installed the .Net core hosting bundle in your server.

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-6.0.3-windows-hosting-bundle-installer

Answer (score -1):

Just publish server Project and upload it on your host.